# text going out of parent div

Tags: html, css, text

I got a piece of text that's coming out of a database and loaded into a div, but the text goes all the way out of the div. Some kind of solution for this?

```css
.teksten {
 width:500px;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
.text {
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teksten">
  <p class="text">
    <?php
        echo $klant[0]["taak1Info"];
    ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP, as it has no bearing on the result. What does `$klant[0]["taak1Info"]` output?

Comment: what do you want to happen? I am not sure what other styles are being applied to p, but white-space: normal might help.

Comment: $klant[0]["taak1Info"] only outputs a textfield from the database from that specific client

Answer (score 1):

This has worked indeed:

```css
white-space: normal;
```

Thanks!